# Something wrong into Linq method

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, list, linq

I have below method:

```
public List<test_view> SelectTypeAnonimowe(string filtr)
{
    testViewClassDataContext tv = new testViewClassDataContext();

    List<test_view> q7 = tv.test_views
        .Where(w => w.FirstName.StartsWith("H") && w.Type == filtr)
        .Select(p => new {p.AutoName, p.LastName })
        .ToList();

     return q7;
}
```

My error:
[image]

Please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: You're returning an anonymous type in your `Select` instead of an instance of `test_view`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you force an Anonymous type into your `test_view` type. You should rather create `test_view` result:

```
List<test_view> q7 = tv.test_views
    .Where(w => w.FirstName.StartsWith("H") && w.Type == filtr)
    .Select(p => new test_view(p.AutoName, p.LastName))
    .ToList();
```

That being said, your `test_view` should have a constructor which takes the two variables as input. Something like this:

```
public string AutoName {get; private set;}
public string LastName {get; private set;}
public test_view(string autoName, string lastName){
    AutoName = autoName;
    LastName = lastName;
}
```

Note that the option above does not work for `LINQ` to entities as `LINQ` to entities requires parameterless constructor. Alternatively thus, as long as your `test_view` has the two properties:

```
public string AutoName {get; set;} //public property here
public string LastName {get; set;} //public property here
public test_view(){ //parameterless constructor here
}
```

You could initialize the properties like this too (together with the `test_view` creation):

```
List<test_view> q7 = tv.test_views
    .Where(w => w.FirstName.StartsWith("H") && w.Type == filtr)
    .Select(p => new test_view() {AutoName = p.AutoName, LastName = p.LastName})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It's maybe worth mentioning that you can use alternative syntax when newing up the class, rather than requiring constructor params, it thats not desired/an option.

Comment: @4est no prob... if you want to let the result in anonymous class, you could try to use `var` (instead of `List<test_view>`) too.

Comment: @Ian The constructor with parameters does not work in LINQ to Entities, you'd better remove that "option".

Answer (score 1):

if you create a new anonymous type

```
.Select(p => new {p.AutoName, p.LastName })
```

then store it into `var q7` instead of `List<test_view> q7`

**or**

create a new object of `test_view` in your `Select()`:

```
.Select(p => new test_view() {AutoName = p.AutoName, LastName = p.LastName })
```

Comment: You can't return an anonymous object from a method, so your first option won't work, given they are trying to return it.

Comment: `public object SelectTypeAnonimowe(string filtr)`

Comment: If that is your intention, then you should declare it in the answer. As-is, your first option doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't creating any `test_view`s. You need to do that in your `Select` call.

```
.Select(p => new test_view(p.AutoName p.LastName))
```